# Verify $n\log n=\Theta(10n\log10n)$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, big-o-notation

> How do I Verify that $n\log n=\Theta(10n\log10n)$

I think I need to prove that there exists $c_1,c_2>0$ such that $c_1.g(n)\le f(n)\le c_2.g(n)$

*Step 1*

$$
\log n\le \log 10n\implies f(n)=n\log n\le 10n\log 10n=g(n)\\
f(n)\le c_2.g(n)\implies f=O(g)
$$

*Step 2*

$$
n\log n\ge\frac{1}{10\log 10}\big[10n\log 10n\big]=\frac{n[\log 10+\log n]}{\log 10}\\
\log n\ge 1+\frac{\log n}{\log 10}=1+\log_{10} n\\
n\ge e^{1+\log_{10}n}
$$

is it the right way to approach the given problem without using limit ?

Note: The original statement of the problem in my reference is: In each of the following situations, indicate whether $f = O(g)$, or $f = Ω(g)$, or both (in which case $f = Θ(g)$), and one example given is $f(n)=n\log n$ and $g(n)=10n\log 10n$.

Comment: I am trying to self-learn algorthms book, so i am no expert in this. It'd be really helpful to point to the problems with this post while downvoting, so that I can possibly address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As constant factors do not matter, you can read the question as asking if

$$\log n=\Theta(\log n+c),$$ where $c>0$.

In other words

$$a(\log n+c)\le \log n\le b(\log n+c)$$ or

$$a+\frac{ac}{\log n}\le 1\le b+\frac{bc}{\log n}.$$

Now take $\log n_0=c$ so that

$$n>n_0\implies0<\frac c{\log n}<1$$ and you need to solve

$$2a\le1\le b.$$

Comment: @SoorajS: why do you tell me this ?

Comment: just to make sure that what problem my post is actually representing, just worried about the downvotes.

Comment: I thought the problem can be stated as, if $n\log n=\Theta(10n\log 10n)\implies a10(\log n+\log 10)\le \log n\le b10(\log n+\log 10)\implies a_1(\log n+\log 10)\le \log n\le b_1(\log n+\log 10)$, right ? so $\log n_0=\log 10\approx 2.3$ and $n>n_0\implies n>10$, right ?

Comment: Taking $a=1/4$ and $n=20$, I could verify the required claim. Thanks.